# Handling nested schemas of AVRO with Python3

Tags: python-3.x, avro

I'm using avro1.8.2 + python3.7 (`pip install avro-python3`) for AVRO format handling.

Here's the sample code from [AVRO website](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/gettingstartedpython.html)

```
import avro.schema
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter

schema = avro.schema.parse(open("user.avsc", "rb").read())

writer = DataFileWriter(open("users.avro", "wb"), DatumWriter(), schema)
writer.append({"name": "Alyssa", "favorite_number": 256})
writer.append({"name": "Ben", "favorite_number": 7, "favorite_color": "red"})
writer.close()

reader = DataFileReader(open("users.avro", "rb"), DatumReader())
for user in reader:
    print user
reader.close()
```

This code doesn't work because that the `parse` method was renamed to `Parse`, and the second parameter - which is needed to support nested schema - was removed.

So the question is how to read/write AVRO with nested schemas in python3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the source code of the Avro library, I figured out a way to do that. Here's the code

```
import json

import avro.schema
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter

def create_schema():
    names = avro.schema.Names()
    load = lambda dict_value: avro.schema.SchemaFromJSONData(dict_value, names=names)

    transaction_schema_dict = {
        "namespace": "myavro",
        "type": "record",
        "name": "Transaction",
        "fields": [
            {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
        ]
    }
    account_schema_dict = {
        "namespace": "myavro",
        "type": "record",
        "name": "Account",
        "fields": [
            {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
            {"name": "transaction",  "type": ["null", {'type': 'array', 'items': 'Transaction'}], 'default': "null"},
        ]
    }

    load(transaction_schema_dict)
    return load(account_schema_dict)

def write_avro_file(file_path, schema, data):
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as f, DataFileWriter(f, DatumWriter(), schema) as writer:
        writer.append(data)

def print_avro_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f, DataFileReader(f, DatumReader()) as reader:
        for account in reader:
            print(account)

def run():
    schema = create_schema()
    file_path = 'account.avro'
    data = {
        'name': 'my account',
        'transaction': [
            { 'name': 'my transaction 1' },
            { 'name': 'my transaction 2' },
        ]
    }
    write_avro_file(file_path, schema, data)
    print_avro_file(file_path)

run()
```

The key is to use `SchemaFromJSONData` function instead of `Parse`, and assign the same `Names` object to allow the schemas referencing each other. Note that the order of loading schema calls matters.